# GameObject muda posição após o play no Unity

Tags: unity3d

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Os outros objectos foram desativados apenas para demonstrar o problema. Penso que ao desativa-los não influenciam no jogo, certo?**

Veja o que acontece ao clicar em `play` no Unity:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que o objecto `Ground` e `Ground_2` foram mudados para a posição (0,0) em relação a câmera (sim, o pivot do sprite é BottomLeft, por isso não fica centrado)

Veja a configuração dos objectos no inspector:

**Background**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Câmera**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Script da câmera**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraSettings : MonoBehaviour {

    private float targetRatio = 9f/16f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Camera cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        cam.aspect = targetRatio;
    }
}
```

**Ground** (os 3 objectos são os mesmos, foram duplicados portanto os atributos no inspector são iguais):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que o `Ground`, `Ground_2` e `Ground_3` são `prefab`.
Eu criei um empty GameObject (e adicionei o RectTransform, Rigidbody2D conforme a imagem acima) e dentro desse GameObject adicionei um sprite (GroundSprite) com as seguintes configurações:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após a ação acima, arrastei o GameObject para um prefab e depois removi o GameObject de cena, mais tarde arrastei o prefab para a cena 3 vezes, gerando os 3 elementos que compõem o chão (Ground, Ground_2 e Ground_3) e logo em seguida fui no menu em "GameObject > Break Prefab Instance" para poder edita-los sem modificar o meu prefab.

Sim, foi uma grande confusão, mas penso que o problema não está no facto de andar a arrastar coisas de um lado para outro, certo?

O que está de errado com o jogo? Poderá ser cache do programa? Instalação com problema? O que será?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54201/discussion-on-question-by-filipe-moraes-gameobject-muda-posicao-apos-o-play-no-u)

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser um bug a partir da versão 5.1.2 do Unity: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1028760/unity-randomly-resetting-gameobjects-position-to-w.html#comment-1028775

Segundo o utilizador, ele resolveu da seguinte forma:

> I solved the problem. It was caused by the rigidbody2Ds position constraints. I confirmed this by having few clones of the gameobject put to the scene and ticked the constraint off from one of them.
>
> When the bug appeared again, only the gameobjects with the position Y or X frozen was reseted to the (0,0,0) position. I ticked the constraint back on and that gameobject was also moved to the zero position after that.
>
> I'm not sure if that is how the constraints are supposed to work or is it a bug. But anyway that was causing the random behaviour.